Is there a specialized formula for molecular friction?

As depicted by the image above, there exists a cylinder made of insulating material. Within the cylinder exists low pressure gas solely comprised of positive ions. Outside of the cylinder exists negative ions. The negative and positive ions are attracted to each other. There also exists an electric field within the cylinder, pushing the positive ions in the opposite direction of its current.
Is there a specialized formula to determine the frictional force of a molecule?
or is the following an apt approach?
$$
f=\mu N =-\mu k \frac{qq}{r^2}
$$
Or, given that we are referring to the friction which results from the interaction of a solid and gas, could I use the drag formula?
$$
F_d=\frac{1}{2}\rho u^2 c_d A 
$$
Given Newtons third law, the calculation of the friction experienced by the solid insulator should equal in opposite direction to the friction experienced by the gas.
Finally, there is skin friction.

Is $qq$ meant to be $q_1^2$, $q_1\cdot(-q_1)=-q_1^2$, or $q_1q_2$ with unknown $q_2/q_1$?

-qq is meant to be q1⋅(−q1). Is this right?

It is an interesting thought (+1), but no it is not a good approach.
Friction is complicated if you look at the details. However, it often turns out to have a simple approximate law, $f=\mu N$.
This law works for rigid objects in contact over a large surface. The surfaces are never perfectly flat and smooth. So the contact is where high points stick up. The pressure on these points can be very large. They might weld together, or catch on each other. When the objects slide, they might break these high points or rupture welds. Or something else might be going on. It depends on the solid.
Given all these different mechanisms for friction, it is remarkable that $f=\mu N$ works in many situations.
For your case, you are supposing the ions are not a solid, but they move individually. Given the attraction, you might suppose that the ions stick to the walls. Thermal vibrations might kick them off every so often, giving them the opportunity to move a bit before they stick again.
Ions are chemically active. They might bond to the walls. It would be similar, except that thermal vibrations would have to be hard enough to rupture bonds.
But this is moot. Nothing like the tiny tube full of ions and nothing else has been built. Cells can be similar. They have mechanisms that pump Na$^+$ ions out and K$^+$ ions in. Nerve cells have mechanisms that suddenly allow K$^+$ ions out, creating a momentary voltage across the cell membrane. This is how nerves generate electrical impulses. But the ions are floating in fluid. See The Action Potential
